# Traversing through json dynamically in javascript

Tags: javascript, json

I have a query object for which filter looks like -

```
"filter": {
    "type": "and",
    "fields": [
        {
            "type": "selector",
            "dimension": "loyalty parent attribute",
            "value": "Most Active Communicator"
        },
        {
            "type": "and",
            "fields": [
                {
                    "type": "and",
                    "fields": []
                },
                {
                    "type": "and",
                    "fields": [
                        {
                            "type": "and",
                            "fields": [
                                {
                                    "type": "not",
                                    "field": {
                                        "type": "in",
                                        "dimension": "corporation",
                                        "values": [
                                            null
                                        ]
                                    }
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

As we can see this JSON can very quickly take a very complex form with a few filters. But this is system driven so I can hardly do anything about it.
Due to a certain operation, an empty array called **fields** appears as we can see in the third **and** operation. Currently, I have written a very hardcoded way to find those empty **fields** arrays and remove such items. Looking more a more robust way to do this.

Comment: Any empty array or just ones called "fields"?

Comment: empty array called fields

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This recursively removes empty array fields.

```js
const query = {
  filter: {
    type: "and",
    fields: [
      {
        type: "selector",
        dimension: "loyalty parent attribute",
        value: "Most Active Communicator",
      },
      {
        type: "and",
        fields: [
          {
            type: "and",
            fields: [],
          },
          {
            type: "and",
            fields: [
              {
                type: "and",
                fields: [
                  {
                    type: "not",
                    field: {
                      type: "in",
                      dimension: "corporation",
                      values: [null],
                    },
                  },
                ],
              },
            ],
          },
        ],
      },
    ],
  },
};

function cleanFields(fields){
  return fields.filter(field => {

    if(field.fields){
      // If the field we are currently comparing has nested fields
      // clean those up first before we decide whether or not to keep it
      field.fields = cleanFields(field.fields);
      return field.fields.length > 0;
    }

    return true;
  });
}

const cleaned = cleanFields(query.filter.fields);

console.log(JSON.stringify(cleaned, null, 2))
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple solution using [object-scan](https://github.com/blackflux/object-scan)

```js
// const objectScan = require('object-scan');

const data = { filter: { type: 'and', fields: [{ type: 'selector', dimension: 'loyalty parent attribute', value: 'Most Active Communicator' }, { type: 'and', fields: [{ type: 'and', fields: [] }, { type: 'and', fields: [{ type: 'and', fields: [{ type: 'not', field: { type: 'in', dimension: 'corporation', values: [null] } }] }] }] }] } };

const modify = (obj) => objectScan(['**.fields'], {
  rtn: 'count',
  filterFn: ({ value, gparent, gproperty }) => {
    if (Array.isArray(value) && value.length === 0) {
      delete gparent.splice(gproperty, 1);
      return true;
    }
    return false;
  }
})(obj);

console.log(modify(data)); // returns number of deletions
// => 1
console.log(data);
// => { filter: { type: 'and', fields: [ { type: 'selector', dimension: 'loyalty parent attribute', value: 'Most Active Communicator' }, { type: 'and', fields: [ { type: 'and', fields: [ { type: 'and', fields: [ { type: 'not', field: { type: 'in', dimension: 'corporation', values: [ null ] } } ] } ] } ] } ] } }
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100% !important; top: 0}
```

```html
<script src="https://bundle.run/object-scan@16.0.0"></script>
```

*Disclaimer*: I'm the author of [object-scan](https://www.npmjs.com/package/object-scan)